# Service name for Docker Compose remote interpreter in PyCharm 5.1 Beta 2

Tags: django, docker, pycharm, docker-compose

I've imported to PyCharm 5.1 Beta 2 a tutorial project, which works fine when I run it from the commandline with *docker-compose up* 
: **https:// docs.docker.com/compose/django/**

Trying to set a remote python interpreter is causing problems.

I've been trying to work out what the service name field is expecting:
*remote interpreter - docker compose window* - **http:// i.stack.imgur.com/Vah7P.png**.

My docker-compose.yml file is:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

When I try to enter web or db or anything at all that comes to mind, I get an error message: [Service definition is expected to be a map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG42S.png)

So what am I supposed to enter there?

**EDIT1 (new version: Pycharm 2016.1 release)**

I have now updated to the latest version and am having still issues: [.IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7oJx.png)

**Sorry for not tagging all links - have a new user link limit**

Comment: Based on this link https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2016/03/pycharm-5-1-beta-is-available/, compose v2 is not supported yet.

Comment: Compose v2 is [advertised as supported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18652) in RC2

Comment: I've just tried to do this in the latest EAP build `145.597.11`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Same problem here, PyCharm 2016.1.1 Build #PY-145.598, built on April 5, 2016. And I do not designate the docker-compose.yml version number.

Comment: Same bug in PyCharm 2016.1.2 Build #PY-145.844, built on April 8, 2016.

Answer (score 1):

The only viable way we found to workaround this (Pycharm 2016.1) is setting up an SSH remote interpreter.

Add this to the main service Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:screencast' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin without-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Then log into docker container like this (in the code sample pass 'screencast'):

```
$ ssh root@192.168.99.100 -p 2000
```

**Note: We aware the IP and port might change depending on your docker and compose configs**

For PyCharm just set up a remote SSH Interpreter and you are done!

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-ssh.html